# Out of Board error - DRC Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, drc, design-rules

[image: Out of board error DRC]

I can understand the error as some design objects are out of the boards defined bounds. Is this error a very general notification informing the designer that the whole PCB is to be reviewed and other DRC errors to be cleared before this error is handled?

Comment: What did one or more of the many the Altium forums that you contacted about this problem tell you?